# Create volume for container running on Azure App Service Linux

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-appservice

We have a SpringBoot app which requires a keystore file located at "/secrets/app.keystore.jks" to run.

We want to run the app in a container on a Azure App Service Linux instance. And For security reasons we don't want to include the "/secrets/app.keystore.jks" file in the container itself. Instead, we have managed to upload the file to the "/home/site/wwwroot/secrets/" folder on the app service.

And we use the following command to start up the container on the app service

```
docker run -d myacr.azurecr.io/myAPp:latest -p 80:80 --name myApp 
-e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE -v /home/site/wwwroot/secrets:/secrets
```

In the app service's log, we have the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Could not open
> /secrets/app.keystore.jks as a file, class path resource, or URL.

It looks to me the volume was not set up and the app cannot access to the file "/secrets/app.keystore.jks"

Does anyone know how to setup a volume so the app in the container can access a file on the host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your purpose. One is set the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true` and you can mount the persistent volume to your container like belowin the docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/secrets:/secrets
```

Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#modify-configuration-file).

Another way is that you can mount the Azure Storage to your container and upload the files to the storage. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux).

Comment: Hi @Charles Xu, WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE is set to TRUE.

Maybe I need to use "-v ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/secrets:/secrets" in my startup command.

Or I will try using docker-compose file. Even I am only running one container.

Comment: @sean717 It's ok if you only run one container via the docker-compose file. Or you can use the second way. Set it directly in the Azure portal.

Comment: in the end, the Azure Storage approach worked...I didn't try using docker-compose file.

Comment: When i try the Azure Storage approache for the docker image "nopcommerceteam/nopcommerce" I got  this message "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs"